# PHP, проблема с файлом php.ini

Tags: php

У меня проблема:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   no value и
Loaded Configuration File   (none)

PHP установлен на локальный сервер Apache.

php.ini надо скачать и вручную установить в корневую папку?

В папке php есть только php.ini-development И php.ini-production.

Comment: абсолютнол никто ничего не понял........ты к ini из кода обращаешься?............. нет не надо вручную установливать в корневую папку ничего

Comment: Речь идет о phpinfo(), там пишет: "Configuration File (php.ini) Path no value и Loaded Configuration File (none)". В корневой папке php также нету файла php.ini, почему? Его надо создавать? К ini напрямую не обращаюсь, надо отправить письмо через почту, а там вылазит ошибка, что надо выставить SMTP порт 25 и еще пару вещей настроить. А самого файла где надо настраивать нету.

Comment: php.ini находится в `/etc/php/VERSION/apache2/php.ini` если в линуксе.......если в винде - зависит от того что установлено и как....

Comment: у меня проблема в том, что файла вообще нет, в папке apache24 (установленная папка apache на windows) тоже нету php.ini

Comment: "В папке php есть только php.ini-development И php.ini-production."  ---- вот один из этих файлов (в данном случяе development)   скопируй в **эту же папку** и убери в конце постфикс.... чтоб было php.ini

Comment: понял, спасибо!